# Recommendations on a backend scheduling app?

Tags: .net, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

We currently use SQL Server, a BPM engine, win services, and even the Windows Task Scheduler to fire off scheduled items.  Most are web service invocations, but some are FTP pull downs and whatnot.  I know there are good back-end scheduling apps out there that financial companies, and other process heavy industries use for things like this.  Are there some decent ones out there that will simply let us call endpoints at regular intervals, and maybe script a bit to decrypt the FTP downloads?

I'm over maintaining all of these different ways we have, and still none are working 100%.  some of our business processes are "awesome" where they need to run on a Monday, then Wednesday, then wait for 2 weeks before running again.

Thanks.

Comment: oh, we are mainly a .NET shop for what that's worth.

Comment: If you have a BPM engine, cant you use an instance of it to kick off tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) may fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Check some online scheduling services. Most of them are free. Some are excellent and do almost exactly what you ask for here. The ones that I remember: [WebBasedCron](http://webbasedcron.com), [WebCron](http://webcron.org), [Site24x7](http://site24x7.com). I also have currently one schedule running at [WebScheduler](http://scheduler.codeeffects.com) since 2008 with no interruptions. No complains so far. Google for more. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with these are that the services I'm invoking or even processes I'm calling are internal and not web accessible.

Comment: Very interesting, to offload the scheduling to someone else. The issue is that you have to expose something to be able to trigger things internally.

Answer (score 1):

We use JAMS Scheduler on Windows and Linux. .NET based and supports Windows PowerShell which is really useful. Also handles SFTP/FTP/SCP  www.jamsscheduler.com